# multiple conditions in bash shell

Tags: bash

I have this piece of code in Bash,
The goal is to compare two files and if files  matches and also no force argument is passed, then exit.
Other way it should continue...

But I got this error  `[: !=: unexpected operator` when I run with no argument and script is not stopped as expected,
When I pass force argument it works OK.
Any Idea please ?

```
if    cmp -s  file1  file2  &&  [ $1 != "-f" ] ;  then 
"do something"
exit 1
else "do something"
fi
```

Comment: Most likely `$1` is empty. Use `[[ ... ]]` instead of `[ ... ]`

Comment: when I use `[[ $1 != "-f" ]]` then I got this error `[[: not found`

Comment: If you get the error `[[: not found` you must not be using bash then, how are you running the script? Does your file have a shebang (first line starting with `#!`)? If yes, does it specify `bash` or `sh`?

Comment: Excuse me, I have missing this start line  starting with `#!`, 
and I am  starting script directly with `./script`, however when I run `echo "$SHELL" ` I got `/bin/bash`, is not enough ?

Comment: @Andrew `$SHELL` is your user account's default *interactive* shell, and doesn't control how scripts are run. What shell does the shebang (`#!`) line specify?

Comment: so default shell for running  scripts is sh in linux distros ?

Comment: Honestly I don't really know how it would behave. On my computer it runs with `bash`, but it may vary depending on your distro, etc. You should add a shebang if you want it to run using bash though: `#!/usr/bin/env bash`

Comment: If you don't have a shebang, most shells and library functions will invoke the script with `sh`. The exception is bash which invokes such scripts with `bash`. [ShellCheck](https://ShellCheck.net) automatically warns about the quoting issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[ ... ]` is just a normal command, essentially equivalent to `test`. As such, if you pass an unquoted empty variable (like `$1` when no arguments are provided to your program), it will try to run `[ != "-f" ]`, which gives that error, since you need two sides to compare with `!=`.

To solve this, you can either use `[[ ... ]]` (which requires `bash`, not being POSIX compatible), which does not make unquoted variables "disappear", or you can also quote your variable to keep it POSIX compatible:

```
cmp -s file1 file2 && [[ $1 != "-f" ]]
cmp -s file1 file2 && [ "$1" != "-f" ]
```